# web fonts that support small-caps?

Tags: css, webfonts, google-webfonts

is there any open web font that fully supports small-caps?

For example if I set [Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) to `small-caps`, the result will look like this:

[image]

You see that the *uppercased* letters R and A have a higher weight than the surrounding *lowercased* letters. This font does not support `small-caps` properly.

Comment: In my searching I found this, YMMV: https://www.1001fonts.com/small-caps+google-web-fonts.html

Comment: @SamuelJaeschke Those appear to be all fonts that use small caps in the glyph positions of lowercase characters, instead of having lowercase characters at all. Sadly, none of those support an actual small-caps CSS setting.

Answer (score 2):

Give a call to the foundry, every font is designed differently, if they don't have the glyphs you wont be able to have that, when I purchased the license for the webfont for the company that I work, I called the foundry I was budgeting they helped me to choose the perfect font that had the Small caps with it.

Comment: This answer is probably more appropriate as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Try using the `font-variant` and `font-variant-caps` css rules. Take a look at the MDN Docs on these properties for more info, [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant) and [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-variant-caps).

> small-caps, all-small-caps, petite-caps, all-petite-caps, unicase, titling-caps
>   Specifies the keywords and functions related to the font-variant-caps longhand property.

---

> small-caps
>   This keyword forces the use of small capitals letters for lower case characters. It corresponds to the OpenType value smcp; if the font doesn't support them, it synthesizes the glyphs.

```css
.my_style {
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<p class="my_style">hello</p>
```

Comment: I know how to set small caps in css. But I asked for web fonts that fully support it.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The docs state *If petite capital glyphs are not present in the font, small capital glyphs are used. If these are not present, the browser synthesizes them from the uppercase glyphs*. Are you trying to use a font that doesn't support it, or?

Comment: I added an example to my question.

Comment: @loominade, this behavior is expected since `small-caps` generates reduced in size capitals. As font-size increases, so does its thickness which makes it look bolder in this case. This is normal.

Comment: Like you said, you probably need to find a font that supports this better. Finding a list of fonts with specific requirements isn't exactly a programming question, so I doubt SO can help you in this matter.

Comment: Actually, Roboto supports "real" small caps, so this is a legitimate question! The small caps are rendered perfectly in Firefox. However, it doesn't work for me when using Roboto with Google Fonts on Chrome 65. Using `font-feature-settings` didn't help.